# Robot Framework Appium WebDriver Exception

Tags: android, appium, robotframework

I am getting the following error while using **Open Application** Keyword:
WebDriverException: Message: The requested resource could not be found, or a request was received using an HTTP method that is not supported by the mapped resource

I have followed the robot framework docs.

**Here is my code:**

```
Open Application
    ...  http://localhost:4723/wd/hub
    ...  platformName=Android
    ...  deviceName=emulator-5554
    ...  appPackage=chat21.android.demo
    ...  appActivity=chat21.android.demo.SplashActivity
    ...  automationName=Uiautomator2
```

**Appium Error:**

```
 Request idempotency key: e116ec36-bc01-48f7-b4e8-b4bf55f51991
[HTTP] --> POST /wd/hub/session
[HTTP] {"capabilities":{"firstMatch":[{}],"alwaysMatch":{"platformName":"Android","appium:deviceName":"emulator-5554","appium:appPackage":"chat21.android.demo","appium:appActivity":"chat21.android.demo.SplashActivity","appium:automationName":"Uiautomator2"}}}
[HTTP] No route found for /wd/hub/session
[HTTP] <-- POST /wd/hub/session 404 18 ms - 211
```

**Appium Version:** 2.4.1
**Uiautomator2 Version**: 2.44.2

I have tried the solutions available on the internet but still my issue isn't resolved.

Answer (score 0):

I have run the appium server by running command "**appium --address 127.0.0.1**"

And change the code to "http://localhost:4723" .........

I have removed the trailing /wd/hub from the above url.

Here is m code for open application Keyword:

```
Open Application  http://localhost:4723  platformName=Android  deviceName=emulator-name  appPackage=your_app.android.name  appActivity=your_package_activity  automationName=Uiautomator2
```